# Data Insertion error while using Spring Roo with Postgres

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I'm very new to using Roo, Hibernate, and Postgres. I've been working on Java, JDBC and MySQL so far but I've had to change to the former platform recently.

I tried to create a basic CRUD web app based on Spring Web MVC using Roo and an existing Postgres database. The reading, displaying, updating and deleting functions all work fine but not the create/insertion function. I really don't know what's going wrong because it's a very basic app and the other functions are working fine. I've tried googling and searching but I didn't find anything that helped with my problem. I'd really appreciate whatever help anyone can give.

**Version details:**

```
JDK: 1.7u25
Spring: 3.2.3.RELEASE
Database: Postgres 9.2
IDE: Spring Tool Suite 3.2.0.RELEASE
RAD: Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE
JDBC Driver: 9.1-901-1.jdbc4
```

***Database Schema:** *public*

---

-- Table structure for student

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."student";
CREATE TABLE "public"."student" (
"uid" int2 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"math" int2 NOT NULL,
"science" int2 NOT NULL,
"english" int2 NOT NULL,
"total" int2,
"grade" varchar(2) COLLATE "default"
);
```

---

-- Table structure for weather

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."weather";
CREATE TABLE "public"."weather" (
"city" varchar(30) COLLATE "default",
"temp_hi" int2,
"temp_lo" int2,
"prcp" float4,
"date" date,
"uid" int2 REFERENCES "public"."student" ("uid")
);
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.sample">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**WEB-INF\views\weathers\create.jspx (made by roo for creating a record for domain weather i presume.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:create compositePkField="id" id="fc_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather" modelAttribute="weather" path="/weathers" render="${empty dependencies}" z="PF86xg+kbnl7RAqTjojWlF4Z3qE=">
        <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="id.city" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_city" required="true" z="ckELowpSAQzvf9cAv6oCYkRbCvk="/>
        <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="id.tempHi" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_tempHi" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="VLv8DnAYnP8Q7dWMOUFpOsX1gN4="/>
        <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="id.tempLo" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_tempLo" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="wxk3KZImWeSNkXxtgFk8xmg7hOQ="/>
        <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="id.prcp" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_prcp" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_number" z="g0pZudMkjApBEG0kGtrzcEMdIXo="/>
        <field:datetime dateTimePattern="${weather_id.date_date_format}" disableFormBinding="true" field="id.date" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_date" required="true" z="mxySE+ylX1MvkpeC32dz6kE1yO4="/>
        <field:input disableFormBinding="true" field="id.uid" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather_id_uid" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="B7pFK6f2H5X8jUsDisVjPiKRaqg="/>
    </form:create>
    <form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_com_springtest_sample_domain_Weather" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="5v9Q9zzCQAQ4XyDzykoEl2YVqjI="/>
</div>
```

**WEB-INF\views\students\create.jspx**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:create id="fc_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student" modelAttribute="student" path="/students" render="${empty dependencies}" z="4DI952XoJPRi7uvp6wH3vh4jH+c=">
        <field:simple field="weathers" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_weathers" messageCode="entity_reference_not_managed" messageCodeAttribute="Weather" z="kF6JmO7MlzSoqhfAd2ZHM5ai8Kc="/>
        <field:input field="name" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_name" required="true" z="OSD2mrzOmmRQA6VBIJPVNVnSCWI="/>
        <field:input field="math" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_math" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="VIm+H0xvZNmMgWvRhcVKfhL1520="/>
        <field:input field="science" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_science" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="Uyq3S34h4XdMpkGZ0/lOm8daWWA="/>
        <field:input field="english" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_english" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="3TeOvLZYSl+T2s9ClWQmMc+XJX0="/>
        <field:input field="total" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_total" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" z="ksAXIgx4f3bLj1Mn3bmEMqZU8OI="/>
        <field:input field="grade" id="c_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_grade" z="wuIbwBuzL0bBpARHtTH1bb9L6IA="/>
    </form:create>
    <form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_com_springtest_sample_domain_Student" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="0oOOhh7rARbZ6RteFU2igEZ3BTE="/>
</div>
```

Well, I hope I've pasted everything important. I'm not sure what's important and what's not, so I'm sorry if there's too much info!

**Error Details:**

**Data Access Failure**

**Exception Message:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
com.springtest.sample.domain.Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.persist_aroundBody10(Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:43)
com.springtest.sample.domain.Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$AjcClosure11.run(Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
com.springtest.sample.domain.Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_springtest_sample_domain_Student$persist(Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:41)
com.springtest.sample.domain.Student.persist(Student.java:1)
com.springtest.sample.domain.Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_springtest_sample_domain_Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_springtest_sample_domain_Student$persist(Student_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
com.springtest.sample.web.StudentController_Roo_Controller.ajc$interMethod$com_springtest_sample_web_StudentController_Roo_Controller$com_springtest_sample_web_StudentController$create(StudentController_Roo_Controller.aj:30)
com.springtest.sample.web.StudentController.create(StudentController.java:1)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Did you create your tables by hand, or did ROO generate them?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve my problem like yours with this exception and Spring Roo/JPA...

You need to review your generated entities.

In my case I generated my entities with reverse engineering but my attributes's mappings were wrong... after updating my java code (and mappings) to reflect the structure of my database tables (pks, attributes, fks, etc) ... I only need to update the related jsp pages and the problem was resolved.

I recommend you configure Hibernate to display the query executed in the log with the following parameter in the persistence.xml:

```
 <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
```

With your executed query, you could try it into your database outside your application and check that it is ok.

I hope it will helpful.